# How do I create a tooltip using on:click in Svelte?

Tags: function, onclick, tooltip, svelte

I'm trying to create a tooltip for my viz such that on:click(), it shows data from my json file, called breadData. I'm using Svelte, and here's the code i've written so far. I'm trying to write a function called handleClick, that will be called when `on:click={() => handleClick(i)}` is run. But what do I write inside the function? The function is working because when I console.log(breadData[i]) it is working as it should. Would appreciate any advice, thank you!

```
    const handleClick = (i) => {
    console.log(breadData[i])
    }
```

```
        {#each album as img, i}
        <img class='tile {hilited[index].includes(i)?'hilited':'faded'}' src='./img/{img}' alt='Bread picture' on:click={() => handleClick(i)}/>
        {/each}
```

I tried doing this but nothing is showing up.

```
  const handleClick = (i) => {
    const data = breadData[i];
    const tooltip = document.querySelector(`#tooltip-${i}`);
    tooltip.innerHTML = `<div>Name: ${data.bread}</div><div>Day: ${data.day}</div>`;
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
  };
```

Comment: Don't manipulate the DOM manually when using Svelte. Also, do not add click handlers to non-interactive elements, they belong on buttons.

Comment: Have a look at `#if` blocks https://svelte.dev/tutorial/if-blocks (go through the whole tutorial, if you haven't already)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use manual DOM manipulation when using Svelte, you could use {#if ..} block to conditionally render your data once clicked.

1. Declare new Boolean variable that checks if image clicked:

   ```
   <script>
     var imageClicked = false;
   </script>
   ```
2. Add your image tag to html

   ```
   <img src="/your-image.png" alt="" on:click={()=>{
      //Retrieve your JSON data then.....
      imageClicked = !imageClicked;  
      }}/>
   ```
3. Use [`{#if..}` block](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-if) to conditionally render data about image when `imageClicked` is `true`.

   ```
   {#if imageClicked}
     <div>
       <div>Name: {data.bread}</div><div>Day: {data.day}</div>
     </div>
   {/if}
   ```

**ALSO**

Consider using a Child (Nested) Component for each Image, see example [here](https://svelte.dev/examples/declaring-props).
You can use CSS positioning to create the Tooltip style.
Hope this helps.